# Can I use #if directive in a C macro?

Tags: objective-c, c, macros

I want to declare a C macro which was defined according to the parameter passed to the macro. In other words, I want to use `#if` directive in a C macro. It should be like this:

```
#define XLType_id 1

#define XLTypeCastToVoidPointer(type) #if XLType_##type \\
(__bridge void *)\\
#define XLTypeCast(type) (__bridge id)\\
#else \\
&\\
#define XLTypeCast(type) *(type*)\\
#endif
```

I want to use the `XLTypeCastToVoidPointer()` and `XLTypeCast()` macro to re-cast a variable with `(void *)` type.

```
- (NSInteger) value{
    NSInteger returnValue = 100;

    // the same as -> void *aValueToReturn = &returnValue;
    void *aValueToReturn = XLTypeCastToVoidPointer(NSInteger) returnValue;

    // Do something with this void pointer here.

    // the same as -> return *(NSInteger*) aValueToReturn;
    return XLTypeCast(NSInteger) aValueToReturn;
}


- (NSString*)string{
    NSString* aString = @"a string";

    // the same as -> void *aValueToReturn = &returnValue;
    void *aValueToReturn = XLTypeCastToVoidPointer(id) aString;

    // Do something with this void pointer here.

    // the same as -> return *(NSInteger*) aValueToReturn;
    return XLTypeCast(id) aString;
}
```

However, it seems not allow to use `#if` directive in the C macro. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: No, you can't define preprocessor macros within preprocessor macros.

Comment: Not only that you can't do it like this, the preprocessing phase also knows nothing about types. It only knows about token sequences. Perhaps you should tell us what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Also type casting a `void*` as you want to do it here looks completely superfluous to me. In C `void*` is converted implicitly to any other data pointer without problems. (My guess is that in objective-C this would be the same, but I am no expert on that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. The definition of the language does not allow this. Compilers do not support this either.

C preprocessor is blamed for being too complex. Modern languages do not use similar features. It is highly unlikely that something what you ask will appear in future.

Nevertheless from my point of view there is nothing wrong of particular bad in what you are asking. I was thinking about implementing this in my own parser but later on gave up.

Answer (score 0):

If this is really only about a small set of types (here I use `bridge` and `toto` ) that all are identified with a one-token identifier you can get away with something like

```
#define XLTypeCastToVoidPointer(T) XLTypeCast_ ## T
#define XLTypeCast_bridge(X) (bridge)(X)
#define XLTypeCast_toto(X) *((toto*)(X))
```